# Find the owner shell for a process

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

How can I find a process is owned by which shell?

It is useful as I have a server with multiple logged in users and a few long-running processes, and I want to know which users can I force log-out without stopping their started jobs.

The output of `ps` is reporting a TTY, but it is not useful as even after disowning a job, its TTY remains the same. So how can I find out if a user `disown`/`nohup`ed its started processes?

Comment: Which os are you using?

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on serverfault.com instead, it is more appropriate there.

Comment: @RobinGreen: Unless OP is looking for a programmatic solution without telling us. But then, we would see some example code in the question, wouldn't we?

Comment: pstree -ap and other parms will show the tree

Comment: @RobinGreen I this question would be off-topic on [sf] as well, it is not about “enterprise” administration. It would be a better fit for [unix.se].

Comment: @Gilles maybe, it's unclear from the question what this server is being used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't find the “owner shell” in the sense you're describing, because there's no such thing. You can find the parent process, which may be a shell; but you can't know whether the shell disowned the job, because that operation is purely internal to the shell.

What you should really do is instruct your users to start long-running programs inside [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [Tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). These are somewhat complex programs, but for basic use, they are very simple.

- Start a Screen session by running the command `screen`.
- You can run commands inside that session, and they'll keep running even if you log out.
- If you want to log out with a command still running, disconnect from the Screen session by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>.
- To reconnect to an existing Screen session, run `screen -rd`.
- If you exit the shell inside a Screen session, the session exits.

You could perhaps make a wrapper script around long-running processes that starts `screen` automatically.